# Select only visible cells

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm looking for a way to take a column of data (70 some rows) with some visible entries, some empty cells, and some formula results. I'm looking for a way to copy out only the entered data and formula results.

for example

```
    T1  T2  T3  T4  T5
    2   2       1   5
    1   6   3   4   
    1       6       1
        2   4   1   2
    1   2   1   3
```

would return

```
    T1  T2  T3  T4  T5
    2   2   3   1   5
    1   6   6   4   1
    1   2   4   1   2
    1   2   1   3
```

Comment: I'm not sure what happened to the first table to get the second table... could you elaborate please?

Comment: Only the cells that had values were carried over

Comment: I'm not seeing no pattern in the example of what you're describing.

Comment: In column T1, there were 2, 1, 1, 1 initially and 2, 1, 2, 1 later. Where did the second 2 go and where did the third 1 come from?

Comment: sorry, realized that i had some typos. Looks like @psychodata figured out what i was meaning to have though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non VBA solution:

1. Select the table.
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
3. Hit <kbd>Special...</kbd>
4. Pick "Blanks"
5. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>
6. Pick "Shift cells up"
7. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Tadaa!

Comment: Perfect! Wonderfully simple. And easy enough I can show my co-workers how to do it. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your sheet looks like this:

[image: start]

Open VBE <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and insert a new `Module`

Copy and paste the below code and run the `RemoveEmptiesAndShfitUp` sub

```
Sub RemoveEmptiesAndShiftUp()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, r As Range
    For j = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column To 1 Step -1
        For i = Cells(Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            Set r = Cells(i, j)
            If IsEmpty(r) Then r.Delete shift:=xlUp
            Set r = Nothing
        Next i
    Next j
End Sub
```

The code will iterate from the last column's row to the first columns second row and remove all empty cells shifting the other ones up. So your result will look like

[image: finish]

Comment: I would vote you up, but I cant yet :( That is to say, THIS WORKS PERFECTLY